# Particular solution of reducible to homogeneous equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Verify that $y=x-5$ is a particular solution of the equation $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2y+6}{x+y+1}\ .$$ This is when $y'=1$ but this is not given as a condition in the question. How would you write the answer to this question and why should $y'=1$?

Comment: Either I am underestimating this problem, or you are over thinking it?

Comment: They ask you to verify : so, replace $y$ by $x-5$ in the rhs and you kow that if $y=x-5$, $y'=1$.

Comment: @Mathmo123. It seems that the edit changed radically. Cheers :)

Comment: Sorry - it was my fault it was like that in the first place!!

Comment: I think it should be like this, otherwise $y=x-5$ is not a solution...

Answer (score 0):

that is to verify when $y=x-5$ the equality is held.

Left side: $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}(x-5)=1$$
Right side: $$\frac{2y+6}{x+y+1}=\frac{2(x-5)+6}{x+x-5+1}=\frac{2x-4}{2x-4}=1\quad(x\ne2)$$